# Cómo obtener el número de línea de un .txt buscando por contenido

Tags: c#

Me gustaría obtener el número de línea de un archivo `.txt`. He conseguido leer y poder mostrar por contenido de una línea o por número de línea, ahora lo que quiero es buscar por contenido de línea y que me devuelva el número de línea que es.

Tengo este código pero no se cómo hacer para obtener el número de línea por contenido.

```
 string param_test_1 = File.ReadAllLines(@"archivo.txt")
                .Where(x=>x.Contains("palabra "))
                .First(); //Busca la primera fila que contenga el texto
                Console.WriteLine(param_test_1);


 if ((File.Exists(@"archivo.txt")))
{    
  string[] lineas = File.ReadAllLines(@"archivo.txt");

  string linea = lineas[19-1]; //Comienza en 0 por eso el "-1"
  Console.WriteLine(linea)
}
```

¡Muchas gracias! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Una opción nos la ofrece la sobrecarga de [`Select`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__) que permite obtener el indice. De esa manera, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
int indicePrimeraCoincidencia = File.ReadAllLines(@"archivo.txt")
            .Select((x,i) => new {Contenido=x, Indice=i} )
            .Where(x => x.Contenido.Contains("palabra"))
            .First().Indice + 1;
```

Como ves, al resultado de `ReadAllLines` le aplicamos un `Select` que nos devuelve un `IEnumerable` con dos propiedades: `Contenido` (el contenido de cada fila) e `Indice` (con el indice de cada fila. De esta manera, tras encontrar la coincidencia, no tenemos mas que acceder a la propiedad `Indice` para obtener el numero de linea (se le suma 1 dado que el indice comienza en 0).

Por otro lado, debes tener un poco de cuidado con este código, ya que si no existe la palabra que buscas en el texto, te va a lanzar una excepción. Yo te recomendaría usar `FirstOrDefault` y aplicar un null check al resultado, por ejemplo asi:

```
int? indicePrimeraCoincidencia = File.ReadAllLines(@"archivo.txt")
            .Select((x,i) => new {Contenido=x, Indice=i} )
            .Where(x => x.Contenido.Contains("palabra"))
            .FirstOrDefault()?.Indice;
```

De esta manera, si la palabra no se encuentra no lanzará ninguna excepción, y en `indicePrimeraCoincidencia` obtendrás `null`. Esta es solo una opción, hay otras muchas para gestionar la posible excepción dependiendo de tus necesidades.

---

Si necesitas buscar a partir de una linea del fichero, puedes usar [`Skip`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=netframework-4.8):

```
int lineaDeInicio = 10; //aqui ponemos la linea a partir de la que buscar

int? param_test_1 = File.ReadAllLines(@"archivo.txt")
            .Skip(lineaDeInicio)               //saltamos las lineas que no nos interesan
            .Select((x, i) => new { Contenido = x, Indice = i })
            .Where(x => x.Contenido.Contains("palabra"))
            .FirstOrDefault()?.Indice + lineaDeInicio; //tenemos que añadir las lineas que hemos saltado para que nos de el indice correcto dentro del archivo
```

Comment: Gracias! ahora estaba dándole vueltas a ver como podría leer a partir de una linea que yo defina y me encuentre la palabra por la que busco, para que me devuelva el indice. Es decir sobre este código como hacer para que lea a partir de cierta linea                                                                                                              int indicePrimeraCoincidencia = File.ReadAllLines(@"archivo.txt")
            .Select((x,i) => new {Contenido=x, Indice=i} )
            .Where(x => x.Contenido.Contains("palabra"))
            .First().Indice + 1;

Comment: @Chr no se si te entiendo bien. Necesitas obtener las siguientes coincidencias a la primera que te devuelve esto, o necesitas que la búsqueda empiece a partir de una linea (aunque esa linea no contenga la palabra buscada) y te devuelva la primera?

Comment: Disculpa si no esta clara la pregunta, pero es lo que comentas ultimo @Pikoh  "o necesitas que la búsqueda empiece a partir de una linea (aunque esa linea no contenga la palabra buscada) y te devuelva la primera?"  Gracias.

Comment: @Chr he editado la respuesta, mira a ver si es lo que necesitas